# how to make a sort stack (min on top) from two sorted stacks?

Tags: sorting, stack

Here is the full question:

Write a java method that will take two sorted stacks A and B (min on top), and return one
stack D that is sorted (min on top). You are allowed to use only the stack operations such as
pop, push, isEmpty and peek.

Example: suppose A={(top)1,4,7,9} and B={(top)2,3,6}, then the function will return a new
stack D= {(top) 1,2,3,4,6,7,9}

I wrote the code like this:

```
     Public static stack myStack ( Stack A , Stack B) {
Stack D = new Stack();
D= A.length()+ B.length();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < D.length ; i++)
{
      if( A.top== -1)
             System.out.println(" Stack is Empty ");
      return A[ top ] ;

            if( B.top== -1)
                 System.out.println(" Stack is Empty ");
             return B[ top ] ;
                   if ( A[top] < B[top])
                      D[top]= A[top];
                   else
                       D[top]= B[top];
  } 
 return D;
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: So, what obstacles are you facing in writing the code? Have you encountered any similar problems before (maybe with a different data structure such as a queue or list)? *Personally*, I'd first be looking at creating a helper method that can produce a new stack that is the *reverse* of an existing stack.

Comment: i edited it by my answer ,, do u think is it true!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the exercise calls on you to only use stack operations (Push, Pop, Peek and IsEmpty) so you can't perform direct indexing as you attempt to do. But some of the logic is reasonably close to efficient.

As I suggested in the comments, I'd first write a method that can *reverse* a stack. That may not seem too relevant now but it is useful. And it's remarkably simple if you consider how one might reverse the order of a literal stack of items - take the top item off of one stack and place it on the top of another. Repeat this action until the first stack is empty and you've reversed the order.

Why is this useful? Because most of your method is going to build the *opposite* of what has been asked for  - you're going to build a stack with the maximum item on top and then, as a final step, reverse it.

So, if you're trying to create a stack with the maximum on top, how do you start? Well, the lowest item on this stack should be the minimum. So, check what's on the top of both stacks and prefer the lowest item as the first to push onto your new stack.

Whilst both stacks have items, you can continue to do this to build up your stack. I'd suggest you do that in a while loop, considering `IsEmpty`.

Once *one* of the stacks is empty, you can just push all of the remaining items from the other stack on to finish this construction. You should realise that you can do this without having to apply too much control flow here beyond a couple of `while` loops since "push all remaining items from an empty list" is effectively a no-op.

And, like I said at the start, once you've created this (max on top) stack, all you need to do is to reverse it.